# The asymptotic behaviour of a sequence involving the sine and cosine functions: explain an strategy to get it

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, trigonometric-series

I was playing with series with Wolfram Alpha online calculator when I've considered the plot of the function $$f(x)=\frac{(\sin x)^{\cos x}}{(\cos x)^{\sin x}},\tag{1}$$
over real numbers in $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$. And after I wondered next question.

> **Question.** What about the asymptotic behaviour of $$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\frac{(\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right))^{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)}}{(\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right))^{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)}}\tag{2}$$
>   as $x\to\infty$? I am looking (as curiosity) a big/little oh statement, or well an asymptotic equivalence $\sim$ as $x\to\infty$. Since my series seems tedious and artificious only is required, if you want, that you explain a good strategy to get such asymptotic behaviour. **Many thanks.**

I know the Taylor series for the sine and cosine functions, and the Euler–Maclaurin formula, see this [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) but 
even this seems complicated to get. Finally one can write our sequence as

$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\frac{\operatorname{exp}\left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)\log(\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right))\right)}{\operatorname{exp}\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)\log (\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right))\right)}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: Everyone in the spirit or my question the feedback of previous answers is enough to me. Many thanks to those users that provided an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small $t>0,$

$$\cos t < (\cos t)^{\sin t} < 1.$$

Thus as $t\to 0^+,$ $(\cos t)^{\sin t}\to 1.$ This takes care of the denominators of you terms.

As for the numerators, it seems likely that $(\sin t)^{\cos t}\sim t$ as $t\to 0^+.$ The intuition here being that $\sin t \sim t$ and $\cos t \sim 1.$ That's not a proof of course. However, $(\sin t)^{\cos t}\sim t$ does hold; see if you can prove it.

It follows that the terms of your series are asymptotic to $\dfrac{\pi}{4 n}.$ From this it follows that the sum of your terms from $1$ to $N$ is asymptotic to

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\pi}{4 n} = \frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}\sim \frac{\pi}{4}\,\ln N.$$

Comment: Many thansk to you and Robert for these details. I know that using L'Hôpital as $t\to0^{+}$ our limit is $\frac{0}{0}$ thus we compute the limit $\frac{\frac{d}{dt} (\sin t)^{\cos t}}{1}$ and from here working (I think that is required one more time the same trick combined to logarithmic differentiation) we prove that our limit is $1$, and thus the asymptotic equivalence that you've proposed to me as exercise.

Answer (score 0):

According to Maple,

$$ f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)^{\cos(x)}}{\cos(x)^{\sin(x)}} = x + \left(-\frac{1}{6} - \frac{\ln(x)}{2}\right) x^3 + O(x^4) $$

so $$\sum_{n=1}^N f\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\pi}{4n} + O(1) = \frac{\pi}{4} \log(N) + O(1)$$

Comment: Many thanks, now I am going to read your answer. I am going to wait  some days if there are more feedback/answers, but yours seems very clear.